# React - Form select Images

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and I am trying to make a form with a select where the user will have to select a `div` which includes a `picture` + a `h2` like the example bellow:

[image]

This is what I have so far but I am not getting any error messages and no form appears on the page.

```
  <select>
    <option style="background-image:url(${process.env.PUBLIC_URL + 'images/aws.png'});">
      AWS
    </option>
    <option style="background-image:url(${process.env.PUBLIC_URL + 'images/gcp.png'});">
      GCP
    </option>
    <option style="background-image:url(${process.env.PUBLIC_URL + 'images/azure.png'});">
      Azure
    </option>
  </select>

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

[image]

Any of you has a sample snipped for this kind of `select`?

Comment: But why select? You can simply write state with selected element and on each div onClick event with some argument like setSelection('USA')

Comment: Yes correct, I am going to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply replace options with your own html tags e.g divs. and add state for keeping that selection item.

```
const [selectedElement, setSelection] = useState(null)

<div onClick={() => setSelection('USA')}>
   USA
{/* your html */}
</div>
```

And after that just write your own styles, logic etc.